# what do I need to distribute when compiling with /MD?

Tags: c++, windows

I am currently developing some plugins. It is build with /MT (static linking  to the CRT).
The problem is we are hitting the limit number of FLS slots.
To solve this I want to use dynamic linking to the CRT with /MD

What do I need to redistribute with my dlls? Is the installed ucrt enough or do I need to also add the vcredist ?

Comment: What is "FLS slots"? In Windows 10, ucrt is preferred, and you don't need install ucrt redist package which is a component of OS. but for Windows 8 and below, you need redistribute it.https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/

Comment: Are you saying the FLS problem goes away if you dynamically link to the CRT and distribute the correct version of the CRT to the target machine? Otherwise how can you be sure /MT is the problem?

Comment: @ravin.wang: That's incorrect. The UCRT is just the C Runtime library. That's enough for applications written in C. You'll still need to deploy the C++ support libraries for code written in C++. This is explicitly explained in the blog post you linked to.

Comment: @IInspectable: if I understand correctly I need to deploy the vcredists with my installer no matter what. So what is the point of having the ucrt lib?

Comment: ucrtbase.dll is an OS component. Distribute vcruntime[X].dll, a small subset of the CRT that's coupled to the compiler version.